# React-App: Prop is updated after the next event

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I've made this "Currency-Converter" to get an idea of how React works.

It works (more or less) but the result is shown with an offset:

You type "1" (Euro) => It shows "0 Dollar".

You type "10"       => It shows "1.1308 Dollar".

You type "100"      => It shows "11.308 Dollar".

...

```js
var Display = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return (
      <div>
        <p>{this.props.euro + ' Euro are equal to ' + this.props.dollar + ' Dollar.'}</p>
      </div>
    )
  }
});

var Converter = React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function() {
    return { euro: 0, dollar: 0, exchangeRate: 1.1308 }
  },
  convertEuroToDollar: function() {
    this.setState({ euro: +document.querySelector('#amount-euro').value });  
    this.setState({ dollar: this.state.euro * this.state.exchangeRate });
  },
  render: function() {
    return (
      <div>
        <input type="text" id="amount-euro" onKeyUp={this.convertEuroToDollar} />
        <Display dollar={this.state.dollar} euro={this.state.euro} exchangeRate={this.state.exchangeRate} />
      </div>
    )
  }
});

ReactDOM.render(
  <Converter />,
  document.querySelector('#app')
);
```

```css
div {
  margin: 30px 50px;
}
```

```html
<div id="app"></div>
```

Live-Demo on CodePen: http://codepen.io/mizech/pen/vGbJxe

It should display the result (euro * exchangeRate) at once.

What I'm doing wrong here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Calling two setStates one after all, you wasn't setting the `euro` state properly.
Being async, you was still using the old value of it.

From the docs:

> setState() does not immediately mutate this.state but creates a
>   pending state transition. Accessing this.state after calling this
>   method can potentially return the existing value.

https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-api.html

To fix the problem, do:

```
convertEuroToDollar: function() {
  const euro = +document.querySelector('#amount-euro').value
  this.setState({
    euro: euro,
    dollar: euro * this.state.exchangeRate
  });
},
```

Fixed example: http://codepen.io/FezVrasta/pen/xVeMMX

Second problem I see, it would be much better to use `ref` instead of `document.querySelector`.

```
convertEuroToDollar: function() {
  const euro = +this.refs.amountEuro.value;
  this.setState({
    euro: euro,
    dollar: euro * this.state.exchangeRate
  });
},
render: function() {
  return (
    <div>
      <input type="text" ref="amountEuro" onKeyUp={this.convertEuroToDollar} />
      <Display dollar={this.state.dollar} euro={this.state.euro} exchangeRate={this.state.exchangeRate} />
    </div>
  )
}
```